# How to select a Radio Button in an ASP.Net Razor Pages app using c#

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on an asp.net razor page that has three radio buttons (All Dates, Filled Dates and Open Dates)  When the page first launches none of the buttons are selected, by default all records (All Dates) are selected.  If the user selects the Open Dates button, only the open dates appear.  However, all of the radio buttons are unchecked again.  I would like the  Open Dates button to stay checked.
How can I set the Open Dates button (or any of the buttons) to selected using C#?  If there is a better way, what is suggested?

```
    //used to filter records as ALL Dates, Filled Dates, Open Dates
    [BindProperty]
    public string Option { get; set; };


    <div class"col-6">
         <input type="radio" value="All" id="Option1" name="Option" /> All Dates
         &nbsp;
         <input type="radio" value="Filled" id="Option2" name="Option"  /> Filled Dates
         &nbsp;
        <input type="radio" value="Open" id="Option3" name="Option"  /> Open Dates
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED: Doing fresh reloads will not persist value for the Option property. You can use [cookies](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-working-with-cookie/) for this.

This is how I would do it:

In your page model:

```
[BindProperty]
public string Option { get; set; }
public string[] Options = new[] { "All", "Filled", "Open" };

public void OnGet()
{
    string option = Request.Cookies["Option"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(option))
        Option = option;
    ...

public IActionResult OnPostAsync()
{
    Set("Option", Option, 60000); // set cookie expiration to 1 minute

    string option = Request.Cookies["Option"];
    ...

private void Set(string key, string value, int? expireTime)
{
    CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();

    if (expireTime.HasValue)
        option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expireTime.Value);
    else
        option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(10);

    Response.Cookies.Append(key, value, option);
}
...
```

In your razor page:

```
@foreach (var option in Model.Options)
{
    <input type="radio" asp-for="Option" value="@option" />@option
    <span>Dates</span>
}
```

Comment: Patee - Thank you for your reply.  I was not clear in what I was asking, my code works.  However, when the page reloads all of the radio buttons are blank again.  What I would like if for the last button the selected to stay checked when the page reloads.  Can this be done?  If so, how.

Comment: If you mean doing a fresh reload where model properties has initial values (Option property being null), then you could probably use cookies or session variables.

Comment: Please see my updated answer for an example on how to use cookies. Please upvote and accept answer if you find this helpful.

Comment: Patee - Thank you!  Modified your example a little, and it worked.